# How can Selenium (or BeautifulSoup) be used to access these hidden elements?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, phantomjs

Here is an example page with pagination controlling dynamically loaded results.

http://www.rehabs.com/local/jacksonville-fl/

All that I presently know to try is:

```
curButton = 1
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul[class="pagination"]').find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[curButton].click()
```

Nothing seems to happen (also when trying to access and click the `a` tag or driver.get() the href of the `a` element).

Is there another way to access the hidden elements? For instance, when reading the html of the entire page, the elements of different pagination are shown, but are apparently inaccessible with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination was added for humans. Maybe you used the wrong xpath or css. Check it.

Use this xpath:

```
//div[@id="listing-basic"]/article/div[@class="h3"]/a/@href
```

Comment: I really needed a pair of fresh eyes. I thought I needed to emulate pagination since the articles weren't showing up as children to a div that, of course, was only containing the displayed items.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the pagination button using:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.pagination li a')[1].click()
```